# National Language Shift Table And Concatenated Sms

Tags: sms, gsm

Can we combine User Data Header for National Language Locking Shift Table and Concatenated SMS?

Concatenated Sms Header:

```
00 IEI for concatenated sms

03 Information element data length 

a1 A reference number 

03 This message has 3 parts 

01 This is part 1
```

How can I add language locking shift table header to this header.

Example of language shift table header:

```
03 length of udh

24 single shift table

01 Information element data length

02 language of shift table
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, you just need to create a UDH header that contains both the shift table and the concatenation header. So for your example above you need to have

08 - length of the whole UDH header (5 for concat + 3 for shift table)

00 - IEI for concatenation with 8 bit reference

03 - length of concat data

a1 - reference number

03 - 3 parts in total

01 - part 1

24 - IEI for single shift table ( if you want locking shift, use 25)

01 - length of shift table data

02 - spanish language

Jim